# Deployiment Issues - multiple webparts

Tags: powershell, deployment, central-administration, 2010

If my SharePoint Project has multiple web parts, then I should
    see multiple .webpart files when I deploy the solution and check the
    webpart gallery, right? If not then what do I do/why is it only one
    web part?

Note: Edited just to feature one question.

Comment: This is a very broad question that would benefit from being split into 3 separate questions. As you already see from the answers, it is hard for one single member to in a few paragraphs answer all of your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the visual studio feature file and check whether you have all the webparts you needed in the feature. Else add them by selecting and send from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your feature (in the VS solution) has all the web parts in it.